# What makes the optimizer stop using the index?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table A with a primary key

```
PRIMARY KEY(c1,c2)
```

and the cardinality of c1 is very low, whereas c2 is very high

When executing the following queries,

```
select *
from A
where (c1, c2) in (('001', 'aaa'))


select *
from A
where c1 = '001'and c2 = 'aaa'
```

the optimizer uses the index.

However, for the following cases,

**Case 1:**

```
select *
from A
where (c1, c2) in (('001', 'aaa'), ('002', 'bbb'), ('003', 'ccc'))
```

**Case 2:**

```
select *
from A
where (c1 = '001'and c2 = 'aaa') or
      (c1 = '002'and c2 = 'bbb') or
      (c1 = '003'and c2 = 'ccc')
```

the optimizer stops using the index for the Case 1 but still uses for the Case 2.

What makes the optimizer stop using the index for Case 1?

*MySQL Version: 5.6.10

Comment: What does 5.7 and 8.0 do? Maybe they fixed this.

Comment: Would you clarify on "What does 5.7 and 8.0 do"?

Comment: Compare vs. MySQL version 5.7 and 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although those expressions are semantically equivalent, MySQL only added the [Range Optimization of Row Constructor Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization), which is actually able to execute them the same way, in [MySQL 5.7.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html) (emphasis mine):

> The optimizer **now** is able to apply the range scan access method to queries of this form:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1, col_2 ) IN (( 'a', 'b' ), ( 'c', 'd' ));
> ```
>
> **Previously, for range scans to be used it was necessary for the query to be written as:**
>
> ```
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1 = 'a' AND col_2 = 'b' )
>   OR ( col_1 = 'c' AND col_2 = 'd' );
> ```
>
> For the optimizer to use a range scan, queries must satisfy these conditions:
>
> - Only IN() predicates are used, not NOT IN().
> - On the left side of the IN() predicate, the row constructor contains only column references.
> - On the right side of the IN() predicate, row constructors contain only runtime constants, which are either literals or local column references that are bound to constants during execution.
> - On the right side of the IN() predicate, there is **more than one row constructor**.